# returning only one row for each value of a column along with other values in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

I am working on a query on a SQL table which has several columns along with several rows of data and the query returns one row for each unique first and second columns based on the criteria given in the query.

For Example, I have the following table `CC`

```
product  term   bid  offer bidcp offercp
AA       sep14  20    10    x   y
AA       Sep14  15     9    p   q  
BA       Sep14  30    15    as  ps
XY       Sep14  25    15    r   t
XY       Oct14   30   20    t    r
XY       Oct14   25   22    p   q
```

When I run the query on the above table it should return the following data

```
product  term   bid  offer bidcp offercp
AA       sep14  20    9      x   q(coming from a record which has lowest offer) 
BA       Sep14  30    15      as  ps
XY       Sep14  25    15      r   t
XY       Oct14  30    20      t    r
```

When I executed the following query it grouped the data in `CC` even by bidcp and offercp and returned almost all the rows as both `offercp` and `bidcp` are unique in one or the other way but I just wanted `bidcp` and `offercp` to be where `bid` and `offer` are coming from assuming pair of both `bid` and `offer` are unique for each product and term

```
select product,term,max(bid) as bid,min(offer) as offer,bidcp,offercp from canadiancrudes where product like '%/%' group by product,term,bidcp,offercp
```

But, when I removed bidcp and offercp from groupby clause it threw me an obvious error

```
Column 'CC.BidCP' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

**Is there a better way to fix it?**

Comment: Do you have an Identity or primary key on this table?  What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Your results seem to indicate that grouping on `product` and `term` would be sufficient. Is there a business logic reason for selecting the 2 other columns in your grouping?

Comment: What if one row has a higher bid, but a different row has a lower offer?

Comment: @AHiggins I am using SQL Server 2012 and I do have a primary key on that table

Comment: @shree.pat18 Yeah grouping by product and term would be sufficient in my case but look at my question at the end

Comment: @TabAlleman That will never be a case, as I already mentioned in the question  that iit is sorted by bid from highest to lowest and offer from lowest to highest

Comment: @TabAlleman What if they are the way you asked like bid and offer come from a different record?

Comment: I asked you first.  :)   In that case, which data do you want to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you need 2 CTEs:

```
WITH o AS (
      SELECT product,term,offer,offercp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, term ORDER BY offer ASC) AS rn
      FROM  canadiancrudes where product like '%/%'
)
,   b AS (
      SELECT product,term,bid,bidcp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, term ORDER BY bid DESC) AS rn
      FROM  canadiancrudes where product like '%/%'
)
    SELECT o.product,o.term,b.bid,o.offer,b.bidcp,o.offercp 
    FROM o
    INNER JOIN b 
      ON o.product=b.product
      AND o.term=b.term
    WHERE o.rn=1
    AND b.rn=1
```

Comment: What if bid and offer are not sorted and they can be from different rows as you asked me earlier?

Comment: Then it depends on which row you want to get.. the higher bid or the lower offer.

Comment: FOr same product and term I would highest bid and its associated bidcp and lowest offer and its associated offercp. I have edited the data in my question in both table and the result

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to get the min, max value -

```
WITH MaxMin_CTE AS (
   SELECT product,term,max(bid) as bid,min(offer) AS Offer
   FROM CC
   GROUP BY product,term)
SELECT * from CC 
INNER JOIN MaxMin_CTE ON CC.product = MaxMin_CTE .product
AND CC.bid= MaxMin_CTE.bid AND CC.Offer = MaxMin_CTE.offer
AND CC.Term = MaxMin_CTE.Term
```

Heres the SQL fiddle -
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6588/2